# Can install PyQt5-sip for one Venv but not for another one! (Pycharm/Win10)

Tags: pyqt, pycharm, compatibility, python-venv

I have a severe compability issue with a Pycharm PyQt5 project that I cannot solve:

**Problem Description:**

I ran into a compability problem when I try to install PyQt5 site packages in my Pycharm editor.

The strange thing is that I could install PyQt5 and used it before in another Pycharm Project about 2 months earlier.

Both projects have two different virtual environments, both created by Pycharm when creating a new environment.

- Screenshot of installed packages of the old, working venv: [image: previous PyQt5 project]
- Screenshot of installed packages of the new, broken venv: [image: broken PyQt project]

**What I tried to narrow down the error:**

- I checked if PyQt5 is still installed in my Python:

> Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in c:\users\mauser\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from PyQt5) (12.8.1)

- The Error Log shows that PyCharm ***fails to install PyQt5-sip*** into the new virtual environment
- Next, I updated both, globally, and locally (in the new project venv), pip and setuptools
- The error log then told me that it needs Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or higher, so I installed the newest version of VC building tools and also included the version that actually says version 14.00.
- Then I installed / upgraded PEP517 since the end of the error log states:

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt5-sip
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyQt5-sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

- It seems that when pip is trying to build PyQt5-sip inside the virtual environment, that somehow the VC+ buildtools fail?

> "basetsd.h": No such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

---

- Finally, I made a new project and tried to install PyQt5 in this fresh virtual environment. It failed with the same error: **PyQt5-sip cannot be built Anymore!**

**Conclusion:**

- Why did it work last time, when I installed, and used PyQt5 without any problems?
- Why can I install just fine: PyQt5, sip, and Qt designer on my machine globally but suddenly not locally anymore?
- Qt designer still works, pip tells me that PyQt5 is correctly installed globally!
- There was a recent Windows 10 patch - was this the reason? Did I maybe not install the correct VC+ 14.00 distribution?
- Can I simply copy the PyQt5 folder from the old venv without breaking anything to bypass this problem? (Did not dare to try this out yet)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is:

**A Win10 update corrupted some parts of the Visual C++ 14.00 package on my system.**

So hopefully this may help some others.

I deleted every VC++ package I had previously installed and (once more) installed the essential VC++ buildtools 2019, build 16.9.5..
Optional Features chosen:

- Core Tools and Test Package
- MSVC 142
- MSVC 140
- C++ CMake Tools
- Win10 SDK
  It seems that you need to include the SDK package as well to make it work!

After having reinstalled cleanly these packages above, PyQt5 and namely PyQt5-sip are able to be built again!